# Using tab navigation causes function to fire multiple times in Lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, trailhead

I added the Build an Account Geolocation App Trailhead components to my home page in a Winter 17 org. I was getting an error with the leaflet map creation in the `jsLoaded` function so I moved the map creation code to the `accountsLoaded` function and that worked. I can see the map on my home page.

But when I navigate to another tab then back to home page, the accountsLoaded function executes two to three times. This creates a new error:

> Uncaught Action failed: c$AccountMap$controller$accountsLoaded [Map container is already initialized.]

Here is the code from the Trailhead project:

```
({
    jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([37.784173, -122.401557], 14);
            L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
                {
                    attribution: 'Tiles © Esri'
                }).addTo(map);
            component.set("v.map", map);
        });
    },

    accountsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {

        // Add markers
        var map = component.get('v.map');
        var accounts = event.getParam('accounts');
        for (var i=0; i<accounts.length; i++) {
            var account = accounts[i];
            var latLng = [account.Location__Latitude__s, account.Location__Longitude__s];
            L.marker(latLng, {account: account}).addTo(map);
        }  
    }
})
```